# Flex Charts Custom AxisRenderer Grouping

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have to group the horizontal columns in all kind of flex charts.

Expected result is shown below.

[image]

On top, i want to display the grouping of the horizontal axis.

Please let me know if this can be achievable in flex charts?

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
Raghu.